# How to kill/destroy PortletSession in Liferay?

Tags: java, javascript, liferay

I am using Portlet to Portlet Communication.In which I created Portlet Session in one Portlet and set attribute.Getting that attribute in second portlet.Now I want to end that session.How can I do this?

Comment: do you want to destroy session in javascript??? <curious javascript tag>

Comment: yes.....but I want to destroy liferay Portlet session

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are catching session value in another portlet controller simply use

```
actionrequest.getPortletSession().removeAttribute("attributeName");
```

and if you are using Session scope it is better to use

```
actionRequest.getPortletSession().removeAttribute("attributeName",scopeId);
```

scopeId can be either one of them

> PortletSession.APPLICATION_SCOPE or PortletSession.PORTLET_SCOPE

And now for handling session in jsp (which i rather don't),

```
PortletRequest portletRequest = (PortletRequest) request.getAttribute(JavaConstants.JAVAX_PORTLET_REQUEST);
portletRequest.getPortletSession().removeAttribute("attributeName");
```